# Calculating percentage in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables with following schemas:

Activity Started Table:

```
ActivityID | Timestamp

  A1            T1
  A2            T2
  A3            T3
  A4            T4
```

Activity Completed Table:

```
ActivityID | Timestamp

  A1             T1
  A2             T2
  A3             T4
```

Now, i want to calculate total percentage of activities completed.

I thought of doing left outer join of both the tables. But i am ubable to think through the solution. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Be careful with division of integers. For example `1 * 100 / 6` is going to truncate the fraction and return 16. You may have expected it to round 16.667 up to 17. The answers below vary in this part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(c.ActivityID) * 100 / count(s.ActivityID) as percentage
from ActivityStarted s
left join ActivityCompleted c on s.ActivityID = c.ActivityID
```

Answer (score 0):

If an activity can only appear in the completed table if it once appeared in the started table, then you don't actually need to join the tables together.  Rather, you can just divide the completed task count by the total task count.

```
SELECT 100.0 * (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ActivityID) FROM ActivityCompleted) /
               (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ActivityID) FROM ActivityStarted)
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Only the completed activities will have a value for the time the activity was complete - using this fact you can obtain the percentage after performing a left outer join between the two tables:

```
SELECT 

CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN C.TIMESTAMP IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(*)

FROM START S
LEFT JOIN COMPLETE C ON C.ID = S.ID
```

Comment: That whole sum expression is equivalent to `count(c.timestamp)`